# htaccess redirect change forward slash / to dash -

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've recently set up a new website for a company. The domain has stayed the same but the URL structure is ever so slightly different for the blog.

The URL structure for the blog was previously `/blog/2015/08/20/post-name/`
but now it is `/blog/2015-08-20-post-name/` so the forward slash has been changed to a dash.

Is there a way I can 301 redirect the old posts to the new ones by changing the forward slash (/) to a dash (-) recursively? but only for the blog.

Thanks, 
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule blog/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([^/]+)/? /blog/$1-$2-$3-$4/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

This rewrite rule should do the trick

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*) https://hostname/blog-$1-$2-$3-$4 [L,R=301]
```

In the future, you can use this site here [An easy way to test your RewriteRules](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/) to test rules without having to actually apply them.

Comment: This works perfectly too, thanks a lot! Thanks for the link too, really handy.